# ASP.Net and postback

Tags: asp.net

I have a form for people to put in info on my contact page. I'm trying to figure out how once they click submit to NOT show the form anymore and show a simple thankyou.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Create a multiview control with 2 views.Place all your controls into one and a "thank you" message in the other and toggle the ActiveViewIndex on submit click

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would just be to use [Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.aspx) controls:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlForm" runat="server">
   ... form here ...
   <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" Text="Submit" runat="server" />
</asp:Panel>

<asp:Panel ID="pnlThankYou" Visible="False" runat="server">
    Thanks!
</asp:Panel>
```

**C#**

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pnlForm.Visible = false;
    pnlThankYou.Visible = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put both sections in separate divs and make divs runat=server 
and set the div which not required visible to false or just add attribute display to hide at server side
and show the other div by visible true or by attribute to block